# How to adjust weights in i-input , j-hidden and k -output neural networks

Tags: neural-network

i was looking at ANN using backpropagation, and ive made one that has 2 inputs , 2 hidden neurons and 2 outputs. Issue, online all the tutorials have either one or 2 outputs or have insanely complicated code, I have no idea how to adjust weights for i-input , j-hidden and k -output neural networks

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you do not adjust the weights by hand. You'd use a training technique to "teach" your network the proper weights.

Training is really just an optimization problem where you are trying to find the best values for the weights, that make the network do whatever you want it to.